# Magento2: error when trying to save data with image in admin

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I wrote a custom slider module which includes slide items form. In this form, there is an image field to upload images.

When I create for the first time a slide item with an image everything is working fine and I can retrieve all my data but when I edit it and save it again I got this error:

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string
>   conversion in
>   /Users/louisserre/Sites/messika/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Data/Form/Element/Image.php
>   on line 51

I got this error even if the image field is not changed.

At ligne 51 of this file the code is:

```
public function getElementHtml(){
    $html = '';

    if ((string)$this->getValue()) {
```

I logged $this->getValue() and i got: imagepath/image.jpg when I create the slide item for the first time and Array([value] => http://imagepath/image.jpg) when I edit the slide item.

Here is my form field code:

```
    $fieldset->addField('image_url', 'image', [
        'label' => __('Image'),
        'title' => __('Image'),
        'name' => 'image_url',
        'required' => true
    ]);
```

Here is my controller Save.php file:

```
<?php

namespace Ultranoir\Slider\Controller\Adminhtml\SliderItem;


use Ultranoir\Slider\Model\Slider;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\TestFramework\ErrorLog\Logger;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

/**
 * Store manager
 *
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Factory
 */
protected $imageFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Factory
 */
protected $mediaDirectory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository
 */
protected $assetRepo;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Image\Factory $imageFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo
 * @param Action\Context $context
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                            \Magento\Framework\Image\Factory $imageFactory,
                            \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
                            \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
                            Action\Context $context)
{
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->imageFactory = $imageFactory;
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
    $this->mediaDirectory = $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Ultranoir_Slider::save_slideritem');
}

/**
 * Save action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    if ($data) {
        /** @var \Ultranoir\Slider\Model\SliderItem $model */
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('\Ultranoir\Slider\Model\SliderItem');

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('slider_item_id');
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
        }
        /** @var \Ultranoir\Slider\Model\Slider $slider */
        $slider = $this->_objectManager->create('\Ultranoir\Slider\Model\Slider');
        $slider->load($model->getSliderId());

        try{
            $data['image_url'] = $this->saveImage();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while uploading the file.'));
            $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['slider_item_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam
            ('slider_item_id')]);
        }

        $model->setData($data);

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'ultraslider_slideritem_prepare_save',
            ['slideritem' => $model, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
        );

        try {
            $model->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved this item.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['slider_item_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' =>
                    true]);
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the record.'));
        }

        $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['slider_item_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam
        ('slider_item_id')]);
    }
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}

protected function saveImage(){
    $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
        'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
        ['fileId' => 'image_url']
    );
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
    $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
    $uploader->addValidateCallback('ultraslider_slideritem_image', $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');
    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);


    $result = $uploader->save($this->getBaseMediaPath());
    $this->generateThumbnails($result['file'], $this->getBaseMediaPath());
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'ultraslider_slideritem_gallery_upload_image_after',
        ['result' => $result, 'action' => $this]
    );

    unset($result['tmp_name']);
    unset($result['path']);

    $result['url'] = $this->getBaseMediaUrl(). $result['file'];
    return $result['url'];

}

protected function getBaseMediaPath(){
    return $this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('slider/slideritem');
}

protected function getBaseMediaUrl(){
    return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
    ).'slider/slideritem';
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getImageUrl($filePath)
{
    if (!$this->mediaDirectory->isFile($filePath)) {
        $url = $this->assetRepo->getUrl(
            "Ultranoir_Slider::images/slideritem/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg"
        );
    } else {
        $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
            ) . $filePath;
    }

    return $url;
}

public function generateThumbnails($fileName, $destinationBaseDir){

    $configs = [
        [
            'width' => 100,
            'height' => 100
        ],
        [
            'width' => 200,
            'height' => 200
        ],
    ];
    // build new filename (most important params)


    foreach($configs as $config){
        $processor = $this->imageFactory->create($destinationBaseDir.$fileName);
        $processor->keepTransparency(true);
        $processor->keepAspectRatio(true);
        $processor->resize($config['width'], $config['height']);
        $path = [
            $destinationBaseDir,
            'cache',
            $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
            'thumbnail'
        ];
        $path[] = "{$config['width']}x{$config['height']}";
        $newFile = implode('/', $path) . $fileName;
        $processor->save($newFile);
    }
}

}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need change the code of save based on action. Means Either new item save first time or any item edit any time.

You can do code like this.

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('slider_item_id');
if ($id) // When Edit Any Image
{
    $image = Array([value]);
}
else // When New Image Add
{ 
    $image = (string)$this->getValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

I don't have access to this value in Save.php file. Error is occuring in Magento/Framework/Data/Form/Element/Image.php on line 51 which is core module code.

I'm sorry to answer that late btw.

Comment: you need to change in your code, so you can access this value in code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the image format from array to string before saving data. To solve this issue just insert given below code before '`$model->setData($data);`' in your '`save.php`' file.

Code is:

```
if(isset($data['image_url']['value']))
{
    $data['image_url'] = $data['image_url']['value'];
}
```